# Definition of the word "embedding"

Tags: definition, word-embeddings, embeddings

The [mathematical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding) of the word "embedding" requires the mapping to be *injective*, so in that context one speaks of, for example, embedding real numbers in complex numbers (ie, embedding A in B that is of a higher cardinality or dimension).

However, in ML contexts, the word "embedding" typically means a map from a higher-dimensional space to a lower-dimensional space (eg, "[word embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding)"), which by definition cannot be injective. Does that mean the two definitions are technically different?

Comment: Aren't word embeddings injective?  It might be helpful here to distinguish functions from partial functions: a word embedding is a partial function defined only on a finite set of words, not on an entire vector space.

Comment: Is it true there is no theoretical guarantee that word embeddings are injective? In principle a DNN could output the same embedding for different words, right?

Comment: Aside: State space reconstruction methods make use of "embedding" in the mathematical sense for estimation.

Comment: I suspect the answer depends on (a) the procedure you use to create the embedding and (b) your objectives.  What I mean by (b) is that you could decide two words with the same embedding are synonyms and treat them as equivalent.  Mathematically, you are taking the quotient of the embedding, thereby guaranteeing it is injective.

Comment: Oh, and [t-SNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding), where the "E" stands for embedding, as a method designed to map high-dimensional vectors (that really could be anywhere in the high-dimensional space) to lower-dimensional ones...

Comment: Pinged you on your other good question [multiindex rows vs columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059089/multiindexing-rows-vs-columns-in-pandas-dataframe). Any insight would be helpful.